# For $S\subset T$ for arbitrary element s of S, $s\leq t$ for some $t\in T$

Tags: real-analysis

> Hello everyone, I wanted to see if my proof is enough. Thank you for your critique.

Let $S$ and $T$ be nonempty sets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S\subset\ T$, and $s$ be an arbitrary element of $S$. Our claim is that $s\leq t$ for some $t\in T$. By contradiction, let us suppose $s>t$ for all $t\in T$. Now, let $s=supS$ and $t=supT$, and so $supS>supT$. Then $supT$ is not an upper bound for B. This means that $\exists s^{'}\in S$, s.t. $t<s^{'}$. But $S\subset T$ so $s^{'}\subset T$, so $\exists s{'}\in T$, s.t. $t<s{'}$. But this is a contradiction since $t=supT$ is an upper bound of T. Hence it must be that $s\leq t$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: It's not true that $s > t$ for all $t \in T$ implies $\sup S > \sup T$, only $\sup S \geq \sup T$.

Comment: @Bungo So if I declared supS=s and supT=t, and said supS>supT, would that mean then s>t?

Comment: Of course it would. But you don't get to choose $s$, do you? And $S$ and $T$ need not contain their sups, unless they are closed and bounded.

Comment: @Bungo Right, must be so for all s, ugh, so stupid. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have to find a single $t$ which works for all $s \in S$, but you have to show that given an arbitrary $s \in S$, you can find a corresponding $t$ that works. As JackR points out, you can simply choose $t=s$, so the problem is a bit silly as stated.

Comment: @Bungo I have just been so focused on bounds that I see everything as such. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S \subset T$ and $s \in S$, then $s \in T$ and $s \leq s$ suffices.

Comment: does it really if t is involved and not in S?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "involved", or which $t$ you're talking about. Given $s \in S$, you want to find _some_ element $t \in T$ with $s \leq t$. Since $S$ is a subset of $T$, $s$ is an element of $T$. Now $s \leq s$, so we can just take $t = s$ and we're done.

Comment: I am too busy face-palming... thank you